# Error installing rb-fsevent (0.4.3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle-install

I'm fairly new to rails. This may be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find a solution. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

I've just cloned a repository and I'm running "bundle install". I initially received a general error message regarding "rb-fsevent"when I ran "bundle install". I then just tried to install "rb-fsevent" individually, but  received the following error message: (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images...)

---

An error occurred while installing rb-fsevent (0.4.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rb-fsevent -v '0.4.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
dhcp-50-74:sample_app SJ$ gem install rb-fsevent -v '0.4.3.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rb-fsevent:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/SJ/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile
extconf.rb:21:in `': Only Darwin systems greater than 8 (Mac OS X 10.5+) are supported (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

---

The error message seems to suggest my Mac system is not 10.5+, however, I'm using a MacbookPro running Mavericks OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, read about fsevents [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) to know what it actually does.

The gem you're trying to install depends on native OSX libraries and you don't seem to be able to build 'em.  Try installing command line tools for OSX and install the gem again.

Here's a good [tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) on how to install command line tools:

**UPDATE**

This was raised as an [issue](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent/issues/33) and the fix is to uninstall the previous version and install version 0.9.

> gem install 'rb-fsevent' -v '0.9'

or update the gem dependency in your Gemfile:

> gem 'rb-fsevent', '>= 0.9'

Comment: Hi rb512, thanks for you reply! I have installed command line tools already but the issue is still not solved.

Comment: ah, my bad, it seems this was [raised](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent/issues/33) sometime back. the fix is to install version 0.9 of rb-fsevent.